# how to dynamically change menu title in VIM's toolbar?

Tags: vim, menu

[image]I am doing a vim plugin for personal use, and it triggers from toolbar.
when I click Plugin in GVIM toolbar, it create a sub menu called 'common'.
When I click common, it start check my vim settings and create sub menu, for instance, show/hide line number. But the following code has some problem, and cannot work. What's wrong with it?

```
amenu &Plugin.&Common :call <SID>createSubMenu()<CR>
fun! s:createSubMenu()    
  let isNum = &number
  if isNum == '1'     
    amenu &Plugin.&Common.Hide\ Line\ &Number  :set nonu  
  else     
    amenu &Plugin.&Common.Show\ Line\ &Number  :set nu  
  endif    
endfunction
```

--------------------- Resolved ----------------------- 
The code above cannot be used. It's completed wrong.
Please refer to Luc Hermitte's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `:unmenu` the old entry to remove it.

BTW, I already have a fully functional toggling/cycling engine for values, than also updates menus. It's done with a function from [lh-vim-lib](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib), see the [test file](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/tests/lh/test-toggle-menu.vim) to have examples of use, and the [documentation](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/lh-vim-lib.txt#L1037) for more explanations.

Answer (score 1):

`:amenu` works like `map` commands: you must include `<CR>` at the end.

```
:amenu &Plugin.&Common.Hide\ Line\ &Number :set nonu<CR>
```

Also, `<SID>` and `s:` are not the same.

You should also probably scope `isNum` to your script with `s:`

An additional remark: why don't you have a single menu entry that proposes to toggle line numbering and calls `:set nu!`?

Comment: thanks a lot. that's very great answer. I am quite new on vim script, so I am still learning ;-) keen to know any good suggestion.

Comment: @heean: a good suggestion is to always learn from vim builtin help, which is well done. Also you can read the vim tag FAQ on StackOverflow

Comment: yes, this is my practice after I read the help. I add the image, that what I wanna build for myself. Actually I wanna know the good functions to implement the script (good suggestion) ;-)

Comment: something like, less code to implement same functions. just like that